# Is there any better way other than iterating through cursor of MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am doing the following business logic in my code

```
Cursor cursor = db.getCollection(CollectionInfo.ORDER).aggregate(pipelines, options);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            orders.add(new Order(cursor.next().toMap()));
        }
        return orders;
```

So just to build the object I am iterating through all the documents. SO If I have a lot of documents as the result of aggregation. The iteration is taking a lot of time. Is there any better way to do this? With Spring data mongo DB or anything else?

Comment: Show us your query. You could use pagination

Comment: You can use `toCollection()`. Also, you can set the cursor's batch size for efficient retrieval of documents from the database server.

Comment: In general, there are two common approaches to list results. Cursor-based and pagination based ones. Each approach has its pro and con and it depends on your design which one is more benefitial. I.e. if you have lots of pages and plenty of results requesting the last page may take up a bit of time compared to a cursor based approach where you just retrieve the next n results in the series. On the other side pagination allows you to target a certain page by intention, i.e. as part of a bookmarked link or the like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mongoTemplate.aggregate(...).getMappedResults()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#aggregate-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)

```
@Autowired
protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
...

List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = ...;
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(pipeline)
    .withOptions(...);
List<Orders> orders = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, CollectionInfo.ORDER, Order.class)
    .getMappedResults();
```

**Note:** If your query returns more than 1K documents, it's recommended to use `$skip` / `$limit`

### Pseudocode

```
skip  = 0
limit = 1_000
size  = 0
do {
   
   //Add skip / limit (do not insert these stages more than once)
   pipeline.add(Aggregation.skip(skip))
   pipeline.add(Aggregation.limit(limit))
   
   //aggregate
   result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(...).getMappedResults();
   
   size  = result.size();
   skip += limit;
// If there are 1_000 results, probably there are more items, keep iterating
} while(size == limit);
```